# How to Speed UP the Effects of Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys

We have a very normalized database. When i do adds and deletes of the data that have foreign keys to tables that have tons of data it takes FOREVER to delete the records not to mention the locks that come from it. What can i do so that foreign keys are still usable but don't affect the performance of my bulk inserts and deletes to the database.  All foreign keys are indexed.

Basically foreign keys slow down my bulk data scenarios significantly. Our clients import hundreds of thousands of records a day, and we also delete large amounts of data every day. Foreign keys offer data integrity, but at the same time reduce the speed of these processes significantly.

Is there any way to sidestep the side affects of a normalized schema?
How have you gotten around these same issues?

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @james xu that is my current way of thinking but i am trying to be smarter and listen to other peoples ideas.. Its not necessarily the right way..

Answer (score 2):

You have not given enough information about the problems you are trying to solve using a database.

It sounds to me like the problem is not the foreign keys but that they are not static and/or you are cascading deletes.

Inserts may require normalization and staged loads so that the primary key rows are loaded before the rows with the foreign keys which refer to them, so there is a little more work there.  Deletes (for range purges) can sometimes be improved using partitions or scheduled batches, with soft-deletes during production time.

So the question is - why is your data churning so much?  What is your specific usage scenario?  And is a normalized model good for this.  Typically in OLTP environments, data is accretive and updating.  INSERTs don't often do a lot of blocking, and DELETEs would only block operations on the same data entities involved in the delete (so you want them blocked).  In an OLAP environment where data is loaded and unloaded regularly for analysis, a relational model isn't always so good, and so a dimensional model may be more appropriate, since the fact loading/unloading will generally not be blocking between different time periods.

Comment: Cade, Your reply may be a little over my head, or my jargan is not up to date. To answer your questions.. Deletes are not cascaded. We are a LOB application.  We import data from many other partner programs and it is usually large amounts.  So if things are being deleted whether because the client wants to make huge changes or loading new data.  WHen the foreing key checks kick in everything gets much slower..  Explain soft deletes.. is this more of a best practices than a feature of sql server?

Comment: @Rico What is your definition of huge?  Have you looked at the execution plans on the deletes to see why they are slow?  A soft delete is when the row simply has an IsDeleted column.  These rows are typically ignored and deleted in batches in off hours (or not really deleted from the table at all, ever).  It is also possible to drop and re-create the FK constraint for large operations.  Note that it is certainly possible that FK cannot be re-created if your delete leaves data in an invalid state (not possible while the FK CONSTRAINT is in place).

Comment: @Rico Typically, I start with the view that you use as many constraints as possible - foreign key, column, row, UNIQUE, NOT NULL, etc.  Later these can be relaxed, but it is very much harder to start without constraints, find that problems creep in and then have to clean up data before constraints can even be applied.  And before dropping constraints, I like to know why they are affecting performance.  Is there an indexing problem?  Is there a clustering problem?  Is there some kind of lock escalation?

Comment: Ok some of our data is heirarchical, categorical if I may. So lets say One table has 1000 records and its child table has 1.2 million records in it.. Then there is a third table with multiple pointers to the second table. An example of the scenario would be that I needed to delete 3500 records from table 2 last night and after 7 hours the delete still didn't work.. How would i go about speeding up this foreign key scenario? point me in the right direction.. They only way i can think to do it is to disable contraints do the delete then enable constraints..

Comment: @Rico Can you post a schema (including the indexes)?